# Spark Job returns result not equal hive SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark

Thank you for your reading. I'm a new java spark. I wrote a jar get dataset from hive database. But jar return result (count) not equal when i test same sqlstatement on hive. Please help me.
this is my code.

```
public void run() {
    logger.info("begin etl for table: " + this.jobName);
    String hdfsDataPath = String.format("%s/%s/*", 
Config.instance().getCfg().get("database_path").toString(),
            this.jobName);
    

    ds = ds.where(functions.to_timestamp(ds.col("Modified")).gt(this.lastTimeValue));

    logger.info("ds.count " + ds.count());
    // query table
    String vanbandenquery = String.format("select * from MPIDMS_07032020_VanBanDen where cast(Modified as timestamp) > cast(%s  as timestamp) order by Modified asc", "'" + this.lastTimeValue + "'");
    ds.registerTempTable(this.jobName);       
    Dataset<Row> dstb = getSpark().sql(vanbandenquery);
    
    logger.info("splitfieldtype=" + this.splitfieldtype + "lastTimeValue=" + this.lastTimeValue);
    logger.info("run job: " + this.jobName + ", query: " + vanbandenquery + ", lastest count=" + 
  dstb.count());
```

Comment: Hive `count(*)` does **NOT** always return the actual count. It's not a bug, it's a feature. Don't ask me why. Maybe to remind everyone that Hive is not a proper database. Anyway, NEVER trust a plain `count(*)` from Hive, especially when it takes less than 1s on a huge table -- the result is clearly drawn from some stale statistic stored in the Metastore.

Comment: oh. Thank Samson Scharfrichter, I will note that. Have a nice day.